# How to calculate no of days spent per month from the data in MS Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a data which has a hotel check in date and check out date. I would be calculating the number of days spent at the hotel, I would simply subtract both of them and I have the days difference.

I now have to pick up the customers who stayed for more than 31 days and find out how many days they had spent per month. For example, some one checking in on 18th July 2015 and checked out on 18th September 2015, there should be multiple columns, corresponding to that cust which reads 13 31 18, for days spent per month. (July, Aug, Sept)

Example data and sample output :

```
Client           Check In    Check Out  

Majestica Inn    22-May-15   22-Jun-15  31   9  22
Twin Tree        29-May-15   30-Jun-15  32   2  31
Connaught Mews   1-Jun-15    31-Jul-15  60  29  31
Majestica Inn    18-Jul-15   18-Sep-15  62  13  31 18
Majestica Inn    18-Jul-15   18-Sep-15  62  13  31 18
```

I am new to Excel, please help.

Comment: I think you need VBA for that or a super complex formula. I suggest you add the excel-vba tag to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can be flexible about the number of columns then you can use the below formulas to get the desired output.

Formula To Get The Days:

Remark: paste this formula in cell e2 and then drag & copy.

=IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH(E$2&"-"&YEAR($B3))>=MONTH($B3),MONTH(E$2&"-"&YEAR($C3))<=MONTH($C3)),IF(MONTH(E$2&"-"&YEAR($B3))=MONTH($B3),DATEDIF($B3,EOMONTH($B3,0),"D"),IF(MONTH(E$2&"-"&YEAR($B3))=MONTH($C3),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C3),MONTH($C3),1),$C3,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C3),MONTH(E$2&"-"&YEAR($B3)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C3),MONTH(E$2&"-"&YEAR($B3)),1),0),"D")+1)),""),"Err")

Formula For Concatenating:

=IFERROR(DATEDIF($B2,$C2,"D")&IF(E2<>"",",","")&CONCATENATE(E2,IF(F2<>"",",",""),F2,IF(G2<>"",",",""),G2,IF(H2<>"",",",""),H2,IF(I2<>"",",",""),I2,IF(J2<>"",",",""),J2,IF(K2<>"",",",""),K2,IF(L2<>"",",",""),L2,IF(M2<>"",",",""),M2,IF(N2<>"",",",""),N2,IF(O2<>"",",",""),O2,IF(P2<>"",",",""),P2),"")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And If You Don't Want To Add any Columns Then Try This One......

[image]

Paste in Cell D2......

=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(DATEDIF($B2,$C2,"D")&","&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Jan"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Jan"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Jan"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Jan"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Jan"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Jan"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Feb"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Feb"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Feb"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Feb"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Feb"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Feb"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Mar"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Mar"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Mar"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Mar"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Mar"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Mar"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Apr"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Apr"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Apr"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Apr"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Apr"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Apr"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("May"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("May"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("May"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("May"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("May"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("May"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Jun"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Jun"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Jun"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Jun"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Jun"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Jun"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Jul"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Jul"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Jul"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Jul"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Jul"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Jul"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Aug"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Aug"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Aug"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Aug"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Aug"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Aug"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Sep"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Sep"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Sep"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Sep"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Sep"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Sep"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Oct"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Oct"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Oct"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Oct"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Oct"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Oct"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Nov"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Nov"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Nov"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Nov"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Nov"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Nov"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH("Dec"&"-"&YEAR($B2))>=MONTH($B2),MONTH("Dec"&"-"&YEAR($C2))<=MONTH($C2)),IF(MONTH("Dec"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($B2),DATEDIF($B2,EOMONTH($B2,0),"D"),IF(MONTH("Dec"&"-"&YEAR($B2))=MONTH($C2),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1),$C2,"D")+1,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Dec"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH("Dec"&"-"&YEAR($B2)),1),0),"D")+1))&",",""),"Err")&"0|",",0|",""),"")

Good Luck .............